# ShellExecuteA but I don't know the extension

Tags: c++, shellexecute

```
std::string str1 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Notes";
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", str1.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The code isn't worth much.

I have an `.mp3` in a DJ program. In one of the tags, it holds the filename of the associated video. All the videos are `.mpeg`.

With the DJ software's API, I can grab the tag. I know where the video files are (all in one folder). I can open the video with `ShellExecuteA()`, because whilst the tag might not contain the full `filename+extension`, I know the extension.

Now the problem - I want to start using `.avi` or `.h254` or whatever. I don't know the extension anymore, and `ShellExecuteA()` needs an extension.

What can I do?

My guesses are:

- If `ShellExecuteA()` returns an error (not sure it does), if it does I could brute-force it; is it `.mpeg`? Is it `.avi`? Is it `.h264`? etc...
- Do a search in the known location with the filename missing the extension, and then grab the full filename with whatever it finds (all file names are unique, even excluding the extension).

I know I could add the extension in the `.mp3` tag, but there are reasons why I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Why you assign `std::string str1 =` then convert with `str1.c_str()`? It is more simple with `char str1 =` and direct `str1`.

Comment: @i486 just a remnant of other stuff going on, unimportant to the question. it actually starts as a stringstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShellExecute` does not need extension. It needs the exact file name. If extensions are hidden in Windows Explorer - make them visible. If you don't know the extension for other reason, use `FindFirst` with wildcard `*` (`Notes*`) to find the full name.

Comment: thanks `FindFirst` looks like what I was imagining. I don't know the extension. all I have is the folder & filename without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

FindFirstA got me the results I wanted
obviously there are more direct ways than sstream but other stuff is going on that isn't important to the actual problem

```
            std::stringstream sstrm1, sstrm2;
            sstrm1 << "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\";
            sstrm2 << sstrm1.str() << "Notes.*";
            HANDLE hFind;
            WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
            hFind = FindFirstFileA(sstrm2.str().c_str(), &data);
            sstrm1 << data.cFileName;
            ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", sstrm1.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Call `FindCloseA( hFind );` at the end or before `ShellExecute`.